# Does JAXB always require XSD

Tags: java, parsing, jaxb, xml-parsing, marshalling

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html#binsch - This article says "*JAXB requires that the XML document you want to access has a schema*"

Here is a Hello World example , uses hello.xsd

http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_1_3-Hello-World.html#Hello%20World -

And here is a Hello World example without using any xsd .

http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Does specification says that JAXB also works **without** xsd ,if that is true then how far the term "Binding" justifies. I believe binding happens through binding the schema.

Carification will be helpful . Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementations do not require an 
XML schema.  You can start from an object model.  You only need to add annotations where you want to override the default mapping behaviour.

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics

**Note:**  The link that you cited (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html#binsch) was for [**JAXB 1 (JSR-31)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=31) which did require an XML schema.  JAXB 2 which is what most people are referring to when they say JAXB does not require an XML schema.

Answer (score 0):

the Customer  class in the tutorial is nothing but a binding object that will be generated from XSD using JAXB. The guy escaped that in his tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

xsd is just a formal representation of xml, analogous to 'Class' for an 'Object' . You can have a compliant xml without an xsd (in which case the xsd is hidden). While it is true that we start with xsd and generate java objects for the most part, you can do things the other way around as well. 'schemagen' actually lets you come up with a xsd for a given java class. This is just to say that there are multiple starting points.